# Hibernate query caching in two programs

Tags: hibernate, caching

If i am having a hibernate program which fires one perticular fixed query.  when same query executed multiple times then, from 2nd time data fetched from cache.
If a other program running from outside, running on the same table, then how can my first program will know that now i have to fetch the data from db?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options:

- Have to get rid of caching and fetch from DB every time.
- You can use distributed caches (like JGroups). These caches communicate over network and notify peers if data was updated.
- You can talk with another application over REST or async protocols and clear the caches manually if something changes.

In my experience using distributed protocols is a headache as they experience all sorts of different behaviour ever the time. So I'd be leaning towards option #1 if I were you. If you decide to go with #2 make sure you learn how these distributed caches work.

Comment: cant we refresh the cache after some interval?